# Asset endpoint returns 404 on standalone network

Tags: horizon, assets, docker

I build a docker image from the [v0.17.0 tag of docker-stellar-core-horizon](https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon/tree/28616e09b2464b802a2e478b2504cd38b211de29).

Then, I created a local standalone network from that image:

```
docker run --rm -d -p "8000:8000" -p "11626:11626" \
  -p "5433:5432" --name stellar synesso/stellar:v0.17.0 --standalone
```

The instance root document is:

```
curl -s http://localhost:8000/ | jq '.|del(._links)'

{
  "horizon_version": "v0.17.0",
  "core_version": "v10.2.0",
  "history_latest_ledger": 1783,
  "history_elder_ledger": 2,
  "core_latest_ledger": 1783,
  "network_passphrase": "Standalone Network ; February 2017",
  "current_protocol_version": 10,
  "core_supported_protocol_version": 10
}
```

I create and fund a few accounts, and make a non-native payment.

```
$ curl -s "http://localhost:8000/accounts/GBZX...MADI/payments" | \
  jq '._embedded.records[3] | del(._links)'

{
  "id": "25769807878",
  "paging_token": "25769807878",
  "transaction_successful": true,
  "source_account": "GBZXN7PIRZGNMHGA7MUUUF4GWPY5AYPV6LY4UV2GL6VJGIQRXFDNMADI",
  "type": "path_payment",
  "type_i": 2,
  "created_at": "2019-02-27T04:40:11Z",
  "transaction_hash": "c5e29c7d19c8af4fa932e6bd3214397a6f20041bc0234dacaac66bf155c02ae9",
  "asset_type": "credit_alphanum12",
  "asset_code": "Chinchilla",
  "asset_issuer": "GAAYHQF2PNZ3H6LE5AX3UJSGUR2DQXHHGXYMHF32TDYF2FFPTTOFI3PA",
  "from": "GBZXN7PIRZGNMHGA7MUUUF4GWPY5AYPV6LY4UV2GL6VJGIQRXFDNMADI",
  "to": "GCYTIVTAEF6AJOZG5TVXE7OZE7FLUXJUJSYAZ3IR2YH4MNINDJJX4DXF",
  "amount": "0.0000001",
  "path": [],
  "source_amount": "0.0000001",
  "source_max": "0.0000001",
  "source_asset_type": "credit_alphanum12",
  "source_asset_code": "Chinchilla",
  "source_asset_issuer": "GBZXN7PIRZGNMHGA7MUUUF4GWPY5AYPV6LY4UV2GL6VJGIQRXFDNMADI"
}
```

In the Horizon DB, the `history_assets` table contains the asset:

```
"id","asset_type","asset_code","asset_issuer"
1,"credit_alphanum12","Chinchilla","GAAYHQF2PNZ3H6LE5AX3UJSGUR2DQXHHGXYMHF32TDYF2FFPTTOFI3PA"
```

But the `asset_stats` table contains nothing.

Because [the query to load assets joins these two tables](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/3d2c1defe73dbfed00146ebe0e8d7e07ce4bb1b6/services/horizon/internal/db2/assets/asset_stat.go#L60-L72) (I might be looking in the wrong place), the call to `/assets` returns a 404.

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/assets"
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/not_found",
  "title": "Resource Missing",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "The resource at the url requested was not found.  This is usually occurs for one of two reasons:  The url requested is not valid, or no data in our database could be found with the parameters provided."
}
```

Most likely, I am missing some important config or setup step. But I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: any traces of log from Horizon?     and, what is returned from `curl "http://localhost:8000"`?

Comment: There's no stdout emitting from the container, so I'll have to chase the logs down. In the meantime, I've updated the question with the content of the root document.

Comment: In the horizon config there's a property `export DISABLE_ASSET_STATS="true"` and log level is set to `INFO`.

Comment: @cesarm I was unable to find any logs in the container. I attached to it and re-ran my tests, but no stdout/err was presented.

Comment: I added `-e LOG_LEVEL="debug" -e DISABLE_ASSET_STATS="false"` to my docker run command, but it didn't have an effect. I will try modifying the config directly.

Comment: Asset stats might be a red herring. Changing `DISABLE_ASSET_STATS` to true in the config had no effect.

Comment: guess it's not related to standalone or docker, my ubuntu package  mainnet /assets endpoint is also responding 404 and asset_stats is empty, too.

Comment: `ENABLE_ASSET_STATS`=true seems to be the correct config key

Comment: That solved it @sui. Please write up and answer so I can accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asset stats are disabled by default, you can enable them with `ENABLE_ASSET_STATS=true`.